# Put a list in mysql and receive in c#

Tags: c#, php, mysql

It's probably a stupid question but I got the following problem. In my table I got a column called itemIds. Now, when a person has for instance 2 items, I want to add these 6-digit ids all to the same field so I can receive them all at the same time when I call the column itemIds for a specific user in my c# api. So my question is, what is the best/easiest way to do this? I read something about serialize array in php but don't think that will work well in combination with c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad practice to put multiple values in one field. You should really use a one to many relation. That being said, it could be done with json. Use json_encode on the php side and a json deserializer on the c# side.

**PHP**

```
$array = [123456,654321] // and some more dummy data
$json = json_encode($array);

// Insert $json into the database here
```

**C#**

```
// Get your data here and store it in some var (e.g. jsonData)

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var ids = ser.Deserialize<List<int>>(jsonData);
```

Comment: Alright thanks! Ehmm but if I use json I won't be able to store it in my database right?

Comment: you will, because JSON is just a string.

Comment: Juventus18 is right. You could us any string based data transfer format. You could us XML but I would advice against that since it is quite verbose and with that it would waste a lot of disk space. CSV could also be used but IMHO json is better since it makes it clearer what you are storing (a collection of values).